# Vehicle routing benchmark instances

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, benchmark, data, split-delivery-routing

I recently started working on the classical split delivery vehicle routing problem (SDVRP). I appreciate if someone could let me know where to download benchmark instances for this problem? I am also interested to know what problem instances are still unsolved. Is this information available and updated in the proposed data sets or I should read recent papers to find out?

I could find [this website](https://w1.cirrelt.ca/~vidalt/en/VRP-resources.html) and it mentions something about "split library" which is confusing to me as it seems to be an algorithm that is not relevant to SDVRP. Any ways, the website has instances for SDVRP with time windows but I could not find simple SDVRP instances. A friend told me that I could also use VRP instances instead of SDVRP instances. Is that a good idea? I prefer not to do this as I am mainly interested to know about the SDVRP instances commonly used.

**EDIT:**

[This website](http://neumann.hec.ca/chairedistributique/data/) has two sets of SDVRP instances (old and new), but I could not find their solution status and that when and in which publication they were introduced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a table of benchmark instances on SDVRP you can have a look at *[Table 4](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jean_Berger/publication/267641014/figure/tbl3/AS:667912717205510@1536254209335/Benchmark-on-known-SDVRP-problem-instances-30_W640.jpg) (Benchmark on known SDVRP problem instances)* of [Ray *et al.* (2014)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267641014_The_multi-depot_split-delivery_vehicle_routing_problem_Model_and_solution_algorithm)<sup>1</sup>. More details are provided in [reference [30]](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166218X9200172I)<sup>2</sup> of the paper.

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Ray, S., Soeanu, A., Berger, J., Debbabi, M. (2014). The multi-depot split-delivery vehicle routing problem: Model and solution algorithm. *Knowledge-Based Systems*. 71.</sub>

<sub>[2] Dror, M., Laporte, G., Trudeau, P. (1994). Vehicle routing with split deliveries. *Discrete Applied Mathematics*. 50(3):239-254.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to check which instances are still open is to check the latest paper(s) on exact solution of the problem. The latest papers seem to be https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/abs/10.1287/trsc.2018.0825 (SDVRP with time windows) and https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejor.2014.04.026 (standard SDVRP).

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to adjust [my vrp generator code](https://github.com/ge0ffrey/vrp-dataset-generator) to generate some SDVRP problems. That way you'll immediately have road distances etc. I used it to create the [Belgium road-km/road-time/air - 50-2750 visits](http://www.vrp-rep.org/datasets/item/2017-0001.html) datasets.

Whatever you do, post the datasets on vrp-rep.org - we as a community should try to centralize all vrp datasets. (I am not affiliated with vrp-rep.org.)